# cross validation and early stopping

Tags: r, validation, cross-validation, h2o

I'm trying to make sure I am not confused with how h2o works with a cross validation and a validation dataset.   I'm sure I am just getting confused on the verbiage that is used to describe this

```
    library(mlbench)
   library(h2o)

data(Sonar)
dfh2o = as.h2o(Sonar)
splits=h2o.splitFrame(dfh2o)

train = splits[[1]]
valid = splits[[2]]

gbm_no_val_frame <- h2o.gbm(x = colnames(df), y = "Class", training_frame = train,
                         nfolds = 5, seed = 1234, ntrees  = 4000, stopping_rounds = 5)


gbm_val_frame <- h2o.gbm(x = colnames(df), y = "Class", training_frame = train, validation_frame = valid,
                    nfolds = 5, seed = 1234, ntrees  = 4000, stopping_rounds = 5)            

   h2o.flow()  ### to see the validation frame stopping under models.
```

1. What is the validation frame that is used for early stopping in gbm_no_val_frame?   How does this stop to prevent overfitting exactly?
2. I think I understand how gbm_val_frame works - it stops overfitting when the scores stop improving when the trained fold/final model hits against the 'valid' frame?

Just want to eliminate any doubts I have here..

Answer (score 3):

> How does early stopping work here exactly?

Your assumption is correct. Early stopping will be used for each of the CV models, and then for the final model.

> If I remove the validation_set here, ...

You are not specifying a validation data set in your example. Instead you are requesting cross-validation, by setting `nfolds`.

If you remove `nfolds` and don't specify `validation_frame`, it will use the score on the *training* data set to evaluate when early stopping should stop. As you are using GBM, that effectively means it will not stop early: GBM will always get better after adding each additional tree.

So, yes, always specify either `validation_frame`, or `nfolds`.

**UPDATE BASED ON CODE EDIT**

`gbm_no_val_frame`: for each of the 5-folds, 1/5th of the data is used as the validation frame. The *final model* is built using all the data. It will only indirectly use early stopping: it will ignore the value of `ntrees` that you give, and instead use the average number of trees that the 5 cv models ended up using.  (Source: the top of p.102 of my book, but it is also in the GBM FAQ.)

As for your second question, my reading of [the FAQ](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/cross_validation.html) suggests that the above is still how early stopping works, and that the validation set is only used to give you additional statistics.

(For GBM I think this is fine; for deep learning, where progress is stochastic and can be a lot noisier, I find the early stopping point of each fold can be quite different, and less useful to decide early stopping of the final model; so I generally prefer not to use `nfolds`, and just use a `validation_frame`)

Comment: Sorry - I meant if I remove the validation_frame but keep the nfolds.   Still same deal?

Comment: @runningbirds We may be talking at cross-purposes, but you do not currently use validation_frame in the code (you showed).

Generally you should use nfolds or validation_frame, avoid not specifying other... and in general using both nfolds and validation_frame is redundant.

Comment: Darren Cook - I will edit my code as I'm not sure I'm getting my point across - give me 3min